# Webpack 1.15.0 Autoprefixer not working with Vue

Tags: css, webpack, vue.js, postcss, autoprefixer

Hi I was wondering if anybody could help me with this.

I have the autoprefixer set up for the past 2 browsers in my webpack file but none of the prefixes are being added. The CSS styles are inside vue components

```
vue: {
    loaders: utils.cssLoaders(),

    postcss: [require('autoprefixer')({
       browsers: ['last 2 versions']
    })]
},
```

None of the prefixes show up for anything though...

Comment: I believe autoprefixer will only work on styles that you `require()` and sent through the css loader. If you don't require them, webpack doesn't know how to find and process them.

Comment: could you further explain what you mean? Like I have to require the actual vue stuff?

Comment: I could be wrong, but I believe webpack loaders will only work if you do `require('./some-css.scss')` etc (http://blog.andrewray.me/webpack-when-to-use-and-why/), which sends it through the loader pipeline. Can you add to your ticket what your styles look like?

Comment: `<style lang="scss">
@import "colors";
@import "font-families";

.uk-tooltip {
  @include lab-font(semibold, normal);
  // Fixes incorrect placement that sometimes happens
  white-space: nowrap;
}

body {
  pointer: cursor;
  overflow: hidden;
  user-select: none;
}

img {
  user-drag: none;
  user-select: none;
}
`